# using distinct command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

using distinct command in SQL is good practice or not? is there any drawback of distinct command?

Comment: Is there any drawback for using the _select_ command? If you need it, use it.

Comment: Well if you believe what CJ Date has to say about it you should apply it always for correctness sake, but he doesn't seem to like SQL anyway...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It depends** entirely on what your use case is.  `DISTINCT` is useful in certain circumstances, but it can be overused.

The drawbacks are mainly increased load on the query engine to perform the sort (since it needs to compare the resultset to itself to remove duplicates), and it can be used to mask an issue in your data - if you are getting duplicates there may be a problem with your source data.

The command itself isn't inherently good or bad.  You can use a screwdriver to hammer a nail, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea, or that screwdrivers are bad in all cases.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use it regularly to get the correct output then you have a design or JOIN issue

It's perfectly valid for use otherwise.

It is a kind of aggregate though: the equivalent to a GROUP BY on all output columns. So it is an extra step is query processing

Answer (score 2):

From this http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Think-Before-Using-Distinct-Command-Arbitarily-1050.php

Sometimes it is seen if the beginners are getting some duplicates in their resultset then they are using DISTINCT. But this has its own disadvantages.

Distinct decreases the query's performance. Because the normal procedure is sorting the results and then removing rows that
are equal to the row immediately before it.

DISTINCT compares between all fields of the record. So DISTINCT increases computation .

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the language, so should be used.

Is some circumstances using `DISTINCT` may cause a table scan where otherwise one would not occur.

You will need to test for each of your own use cases to see if there is an impact and find a workaround if the impact is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the work to make sure the results are distinct to happen inside the SQL server on the SQL machine, then use it.  If you don't mind sending extra results to the client and doing the work there (to reduce server load) then do that.  It depends on your performance requirements and the characteristics of your database.

For example, if it's extremely unlikely that distinct will reduce the result set much, and you don't have the right columns indexed to make it fast, and you need to reduce SQL Server load, and you have spare cycles on the client, and it's easy to ensure distinctness on the client -- then you might want to do that.

That's a lot of ifs, ands, and mights.  If you don't know -- just use it.